# What is SparkSession.read() Dataset<Row> limit reading in Cassandra table? (Spark performance)

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I'm using `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` to read a `Cassandra` table to `Spark` `Dataset<Row>`. The dataset has the whole table information and if I add a new row into `Cassandra` it seems to be working asynchronously in the background and updates the dataset with the row, without reading the table again.

1. Is there any way to limit or is there built in limit for the data read in from the table?
2. What's the size of a `Dataset<Row>` that `Spark` starts to find difficult to process?
3. What are the requirements for `Spark` to handle calculations if `Cassandra` table is half a terabyte?
4. If `Spark` wants to write a large new table of information into `Cassandra`, does it cause more problems for `Spark` to write it in `Cassandra` or for `Cassandra` to read it? I just wonder which product would cause data loss or break down first.

If someone could tell me how `SparkSession` `.read()` exactly works in the background or `Dataset<Row>` and what they require to preform well, would be really useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SparkSession.read()` invokes the underlying datasource's scan method. For Cassandra that is the Spark Cassandra Connector.

The Spark Cassandra Connector breaks up the C* token ring into chunks, each chunk more or less becomes a Spark Partition. Single Spark partitions are then read in each executor core.

A video explaining this [at Datastax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/how-spark-cassandra-connector-reads-data)

The actual size of the Row is pretty unrelated to stability, the data is broken up by token range so you only should end up with difficulties if the underlying Cassandra data has very large hot spots. This would lead to very large Spark Partitions which could lead to memory issues. In general a well distributed C* database should have no problems at any size.

Comment: Thank you!! Btw can't see that video when I'm logged in. `"You are not authorized to access this page."`